# loop:true in owl carousel 2.0.0 offsetting images in Chrome iOS

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I'm using Owl carousel @version 2.0.0

Site in question: http://miracon.ca/homes/prima/ (please view the "gallery"). I have this working pretty reliably in Safari on iPhone but there is a problem in Chrome iOS. The images are not centering properly. Here is my init code:

```
$("#pjct-gallery-content").owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    loop:true,
    margin:28,
    autoWidth:true,
    dots:true,
    autoHeight:true,
    responsive : {
        500 : {
            items:1
        },
        700 : {
            items:2
        },
        900 : {
            items:3
        },
        1400 : {
            items:4
        }
    }
});
```

If I set "loop:false" it works nicely and the first image centers as it should. Set "loop:true" and it does not center as expected.